# android access member variable of extended customListAdapter

Tags: java, android, syntax

I'm facing strange OOP behaviour (IMO) in android and maybe in Java in general...
I have an activity and inside of it I instantiate an object of `CustomSimpleCursorAdapter` which is a class extending `SimpleCursorAdapter`. In my custom class I have some member variables added.
When I create an object of that class I want to be able to access a member variable of newly created object. My OOP experience was telling me that the following should suffice:

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new TrainingsListCursorAdapter(...);
listAdapter.currentWidth = 100;
```

NOTE: *currentWith* variable is declared public...

(Eclipse) didn't want to compile, so I thought maybe a public setter `setCurrentWidth()`in the custom class would solve it. I declared a member variable private and my setter method public....

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new TrainingsListCursorAdapter(...);
listAdapter.setCurrentWidth(100);
```

Eclipse wasn't pleased either... I knew it was a long shot, but when you face strange behaviour, you start to behave strange too :)))

The correction that eclipse was intrusively offering and in the end works! is the following code:

```
((TrainingsListCursorAdapter) listAdapter).setOrientationWidth(100);
```

Could someone please explain me this syntax and need for such casting?! 
...and what's wrong with:

- instantiate an object
- access it public setters/getters or directly member variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not particularly strange at all. The variable `listAdapter` is just of type `ListAdapter`. The compiler couldn't care less what assignments have occurred on previous lines. If you try to access a member which isn't known via `ListAdapter`, the compiler will correctly complain.

A simpler fix than casting would be to declare the variable as being the type you *need* it to be in order to access your specific members:

```
TrainingsListCursorAdapter listAdapter = new TrainingsListCursorAdapter(...);
listAdapter.currentWidth = 100;
```

or

```
TrainingsListCursorAdapter listAdapter = new TrainingsListCursorAdapter(...);
listAdapter.setOrientationWidth(100);
```

So to answer your final point - there's nothing wrong with instantiating an object and accessing public members. There *is* something wrong with trying to do so via a variable of a type which doesn't know about those members.

To give a simpler example in common types, you can't write:

```
Object text = "hello";
int length = text.length();
```

because `length()` is a method on `Object`, it's only on `String`. When the compiler sees the expression `text.length()`, it looks at the declared type of the variable `text` (i.e. `Object` in this case) and looks for the `length()` method on that type.

So this is what you'd do instead to make the above code work:

```
String text = "hello";
int length = text.length();
```

Comment: I thought that compiler will take into account the extension of the parent class...
Thank you so much... You learn something new every day ;)

Comment: @luigi7up: But how would it know *which* subclasses to take into account? Would you expect it to find *every* member of *every* subclass when using a variable of type `Object`?